# Wildcard route declared at sub module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I created a **CoreModule** that's imported in the **AppModule** after the **AppRoutingModule** where I specify the entry point to the app, but I'm having the problem that when the app launches it displays the wildcard route, here's my code:

**CoreRoutingModule**

```
export const CoreRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
]);
```

**CoreModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ NotFoundComponent ]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```
export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: AppComponent }
]);
```

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I access to http://localhost/ what the app displays is the wildcard route with the `NotFoundComponent` when it should display the `AppComponent`

Working env: Angular 2.4.3, Router 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is exactly wrong with your code. cant test without all files. anyway I guess this would work. Try this... add the (pathMatch) and redirectTo

```
    export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/whereToGo', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]);
```

please refer this. Hope it helps.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#default-route

Comment: I've provided the necessary code to reproduce the problem, the `pathMatch='full'` property didn't help

Comment: Dude, the entry point of the app is `' '`, I don't want to redirectTo another route, if I add the wildcard route at the AppRoutingModule everything works fine, but if I create it at another module it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

First routes are matched at root level and in order.

In your case ** comes before '' therefore ** route is rendered.